# Trigger Javascript event on remote website with Python

Tags: javascript, python, dom, web-scraping

I wrote some basic Python code to scrape a remote webpage and grab a few pieces of data. On a different page I'm trying to scrape, the data is hidden from view, and only appears after changing the value of a `<select>` box.

After de-minifying and digging through the remote website's javascript, I confirmed that it is using AJAX (custom implementation of Prototype I think) to switch the `<tbody>` of the `<table>` I'm interested in scraping.

Is there a way to use Python (or Javascript via Python) to trigger the onChange event of that select box so I can "refresh" the DOM and grab the new HTML?

Comment: Why not just do the AJAX request directly and parse the data you want from that?

Comment: Take a look at PySide's WebKit bindings - you can do exactly that. (I'm working on a similar project)

Comment: @kindall i originally couldn't find the ajax request url (was using chrome's built-in inspect element tool). then a friend suggested i use firebug on firefox (which i use normally, but stupidly didnt think to try) and the request url popped up in the console as expected. if you want to post an answer i'll accept yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figure out the AJAX request URL and request it directly.  :-)

Comment: Totally agreed but...
How?

I know the url I have to call from python to achieve the function I need but I don't know how to call it from python. I've tried urllib2.urlopen but it won't do the job... (url is: http://mypc/automation/ajaxinterface.php?do=toggleStatus&status=1&deviceid=1)