# Python how to call AJAX URL (to trigger onchange event for website select menu)

Tags: python, ajax, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to automate Internet Explorer interaction with a website using Python. I am using the IEC library to do this.

The website is set to trigger an action whenever a username is selected from a dropdown menu. The html code snippet is as follows:

```
<select name="ClientID" tabIndex="1001" title="Select a client" class="client-select focus-default need-focus-object valid" style="width: auto;" onchange="localChangeClient()">
  <option value="0">
  <option value="2629049">
```

I am able to programmatically set the user name in the dropdown list, but this does not trigger the "onchange" event. I have read some other references (links below) that indicate I should look for the AJAX request and trigger it directly, but I am not sure how to do this.

1. [Trigger Javascript event on remote website with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937190/trigger-javascript-event-on-remote-website-with-python)
2. [on Change of dropdown list showld call the php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108495/on-change-of-dropdown-list-showld-call-the-php-function)

I gather that 'onchange' triggers a call to a function called localChangeClient(). How do I call / trigger that function directly from Python IEC?

From the examples I linked, it seems an AJAX request would be made inside that localChangeClient function - is that right? How do I know what the AJAX request to call is, given that I cannot see the actual function details?

**EDIT: The following describes continued efforts / developments. I think I just need to know how to call an AJAX URL directly**

So I was reading more about AJAX requests. I found out I could use Firebug (Console window) to tell me the particular AJAX url that gets called for the onchange event. Firebug told me the following (snipped for clarity) when I changed the dropdown menu:

```
POST https://example.com/MyBasket/MyBasket.asp?update=Update%20Basket&ClientID=2629049,0&SDT=417.577989&SCheck=49913&Checkout=&ClientID=2629049&ClientID=0&CurrentPageUrl=&FullPage=false&MyBasketPage=1&OnClickScheduleCheckboxName=&OverlayRequest=true&TransactionStarted=0&ajax=true&cbxRegQuantity=1&cbxRegQuantity=1&update=no
```

So I think I am on the right track. **But now I don't know how to trigger that url from Python.** If I simply "ie.Navigate(url)", it does not seem to work. It takes me to a non-formatted window, and the dropdown menu is still not selected.

I checked a Microsoft support site (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167658), which talked about encoding the request data as bytes etc, but I was unclear if that would apply here.

**I would really appreciate if someone could provide some details on how to "do the AJAX request directly"**

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library to make the call to that URL you found. You'll also need to find the body and any custom HTTP headers of that POST request in the Firebug console in order to replicate it in your script.

```
res = requests.post(<url>, data=<request-body>, headers=<headers>)
```